# How do I put a check constraint on the first letter of names in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, check-constraints

I am new at SQLPlus and I want to enforce a CHECK CONSTRAINT on a column that stores names.

I want the constraint to not allow for names to be entered that starts with a Q.

this is what I have:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD CONSTRAINT table1_name_ck CHECK( name, substr(1,1) ='q');
```

I am getting the errors:

```
cannot validate (USER1.TABLE1_NAME_CK) - check constraint violated
```

AND errors

```
CHECK( name, substr(1,1) ='q')
        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator.
```

I cannot figure out how to fix these errors or find the correct way to implement this. Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks!. I don't think this code work for lowercase q and uppercase Q but I'm just trying that out for now.

Comment: Shall we warn Quentin?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the column  to the `substr` call:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 
   ADD CONSTRAINT table1_name_ck CHECK( substr(name, 1,1) ='q' );
```

To make this work for upper and lowercase you need to enhance this a bit:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 
   ADD CONSTRAINT table1_name_ck CHECK( substr(name, 1,1) NOT IN ('q','Q') );
```

Comment: `not in`, surely? The question says *not* allow starting with Q, despite the attempts using `=`. The OP's use of `=` instead of `!=` might cause the 'cannot validate' error too, at least if that constraint had been valid...

Comment: Thank you! I tried that and it is still giving me the cannot validate -check constraint violated error? Do you know how to resolve that?

Comment: That means you have values in that column that do not start with `q` or `Q`